# Advice on Naming Things

Tags: naming-conventions

I have a list, and I'm trying to decide whether to call it `item` or `items`.  If I call it `items`, it's clear that `foo(items)` is being passed a list of items and not a single item.  On the other hand, I would prefer to write `item[i]` to refer to a particular element instead of `items[i]` (because I would say "bring me item 7", not "bring me items 7").

I also have a function, and I'm trying to decide whether to call it `value` or `get_value`.  If I call it `value`, I can write nice statements like `value_squared = value() ^ 2` (which I think is nicer than `value_squared = get_value() ^ 2`), but I might run into problems writing stuff like `value = value()`, whereas `value = get_value()` would not be problematic.

(I know that this question does not have a right answer, and that it is two questions.  I am open to suggestions that I edit/remove/move/split it, etc., as I'm not quite sure what the right thing to do is.  I would, however, like to see some responses, since I'd like to write code in a way that is easy for others to understand.)

Comment: Consider what language you are using too and have a look at conventions therein. i.e. It is standard **not** to prefix accessors with get in objective-c. i.e. `person.getName()` in java is by convention `person.name` in obj-c.

Comment: I agree with James. This is impossible to answer without knowing the language in question. Every sufficiently widespread language has its own idioms you should obey.

Comment: @musiKk At the moment, I'm mostly interested in Python, for which I couldn't find any guidance on this issue.  I agree that following established conventions is best though, and I see from James's comment that such conventions exist for some languages at least.  I guess I'm also interested in this from a philosophical perspective though: i.e. if you were to design a new language, which convention would you encourage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like plural names for lists and 'get' prefix for functions. I think immediately knowing that they are lists and functions outweighs the negatives.

Answer (score 3):

Call the list (the "container") "items".  Call each element in the list an "item" :)

"items[i]" is perfectly appropriate.

So is:

```
  foreach (ListItem item in items) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is always about preference, do what you or if you are on a team-what the team does.**

It's about the shop you work at and not about being right or wrong.  Besides it's just a name.

In my case I don't like to add `"s"'s` to anything.  For instance, if I am designing a database system of issues with related comments I call my Issues table `Issue`, because one single tuple (or row) represents a single issue.  Same for my Comments table I end up naming it `Comment`.  I don't care that the total of all rows represents "Issues", to me the table represents one entity.  **But again this is personal preference.**

You also mentioned this:

`On the other hand, I would prefer to write item[i] to refer to a particular element instead of items[i] (because I would say "bring me item 7", not "bring me items 7").`

But if your list is called `items` then if you did `items[i]` it should be a no brainer to see that you are referring to one item in the list.  To me this is very readable.

As for your second point it really depends, do you really want to use value?  In some languages that may be a reserved word.  If the function returns a value why not `getValue()` ?  I don't see any harm in that.  Just be consistent with your entire project, it will benefit you and others looking at your code.